# Python Recursion and Tuples

Tags: python, recursion

I am struggling with this recursion problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Write a function named clear that accepts one argument, a tuple of any length, and returns a tuple of the same length with every element set to 0.

Here is my current code:

```
def clear(tup):
    if len(tup) == 0:
        return tup
    else:
        tup[0] = 0
        return clear(tup - tup[0]) + tup[0]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: so whats wrong with your current code

Comment: I don't know that's why I asked?? @JoranBeasley

Comment: This code does not execute; there are multiple basic problems with it.  I recommend that you return to your course materials on tuples and try to execute each of these statements with actual values.  For instance, try /// tup = (1, 2) /// tup[0] = 0 /// You'll see the problem.

Comment: To be clear: This is a recursion problem because whoever assigned it to you (or whatever exercise you got it from) instructs you to use recursion in the answer? (I say this because normally no one would use recursion for this.)

Comment: Yeah, it was assigned as a recursive problem. I would be able to do it easily if that were not the case, and I'm confused as to why recursion is even taught anymore.

Comment: meh conside `x = [1,2,3,[1,[5,6],[7,[8,9]],3]` @Two-BitAlchemist ... I know you dont need recursion but it can help... and from a personal standpoint I have an easier time thinking of things in recursive terms(even if recursion in python is not great)

Comment: @ryanturf do you have the actual problem statement from the assignment?  I suspect the teacher wants arbitrarily deep nested lists, and the recursive part is meant to deal with depth not length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved without recursion:

```
def clear(tup):
    return (0,) * len(tup)
```

However if you really want to do it using recursion:

```
def clear(tup):
    if not tup:
        return ()
    return( (0,) + clear(tup[1:]) )
```

To be more thorough, you may want to do some type checking.  As written, both examples will work for inputs that are tuples, lists, strings and anything that obeys the slicing interface.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought of making a new tuple but this makes perfect sense.

Comment: this wont work for `[1,2,[3,4]]` as Im sure the expected output would be `[0,0,[0,0]]` (ie I think the recursion is for the depth of the list ... not just the  items in the list ...)

Comment: Joran, the problem statement was to accept a tuple and return a tuple of the same length.  No mention of what the sub-elements of the tuple are.

Comment: I agree the OP probably did not word the problem statement the teacher gave him correctly, however from the context we can infer that they want it arbitrarrily deeply nested (since that is the only senario where recursion makes any sense at all)

Comment: apparently I stand corrected ...

Answer (score 4):

```
def clear(tup):
    return tuple(0 if not isinstance(e,(list,tuple)) else clear(e) for e in tup)
```

it may make more sense for the check to check for any iterable subelement

```
if isinstance(e, collections.Iterable)
```

I guess ...

Comment: this does recurse ...

Comment: @Joran Beasley, look at that **else clear(e)** near the end.

Comment: especially since I think the recursion is to handle arbitrary depth not arbitrary length

Comment: based on OP;s accepted answer I guess he does not need to handle nested tuples :/